# NetworkError:Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load 'http://~~/Servlet'

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, jsp, servlets

I have a problem at execute send form.
Executing at localhost no problem.

NetworkError:Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load 'http://~~/Servlet'.

web.xml

```
<servlet>
<servlet-name>GCMServlet</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>com.plantynet.mobile.mng.gcm.GCMServlet</servlet-class>
```

```
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>GCMServlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/GCMServlet</url-pattern>
```

sendForm.jsp

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/djemals/GCMServlet",
                data:"searchType="+searchType+"&searchPhone="+searchPhone+"&note="+note+"&alertType="+alertType,
                async:false,

                success: function (data){

                    alert(data);
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert("ERROR" + textStatus + " : " + errorThrown);
                    self.close();

                }
              });
```

Please help me. TT